Integrating Flutter Web with Unhosted React.js Application
Hello Flutter community,
I'm currently working on a project where I need to integrate a Flutter web application with an existing unhosted React.js application. Despite exploring various approaches, I've encountered challenges in achieving this integration.
I attempted to follow the instructions provided in this tutorial(https://subeg7.medium.com/embedding-an-un-hosted-react-js-app-in-flutter-app-for-viewing-pdf-in-mobile-6ad9c96c7210) using our latest version of Flutter, but unfortunately, I haven't had success.
Could someone please guide me on how to load a React.js application within our Flutter project directory and successfully integrate it?
Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights you can provide.
I have kept React.js application inside flutter asset folder try to load but didn't succeeded.
